# Unable to Upload Image to Media Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload

I have faced some problems to upload the image in Django. After I submit the form, the image URL is successfully inserted to the database but there is no image created to the media file.

Can you guys please help me to find where is the problem. Thank you.

Here is the code.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/images/')
```

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
   img = models.ImageField(upload_to='testing')
```

views.py

```
def goProfile(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
    image = Image(
        img = request.POST.get('imgTest')
    )
    image.save()

 return render(request,'profile.html')
```

profile.html

```
        <form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="file" name="imgTest" id="imgTest">
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Could you please share the error trace?

Comment: @Sabil The problem is solved now. The solution is down below. And also, thank you for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form try this

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="file" name="imgTest" id="imgTest">
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

also  request.FILES in your views